# Drools: use variable instead of attribute name for setName and getName methods

Tags: variables, get, attributes, set, drools

I can use below `setAttributename` to change an attribute of any object. Is it possible to use a variable or position number instead of attribute name @ drools.

Thanks for support.

```
rule "print"
    salience(5)
    when
    ....
    then
       modify($Object1){set-Attribute1 or 2 or 5 with a variable-("...");};
end
```

Comment: If you need to set an unknown number of attributes you would be better with one attribute as a list, map, etc which you could iterate through.

Alternatively if you know exactly how many attributes you have and just want to cut down on code you could separate setting the attributes into a function in the rule.

Comment: @Neil
Thank you very much Neil. 
I know exactly how many attributes I have. If you have time could you please response below questions. 
1- Should I write this function or can I use a library 
2- Are getName & setName also functions as you mention. If it is, where are they defined. If not, are they how many default function like them in drools 
3- If I write the function, will it create additional complexity & problem & delay on code

Comment: Can you provide more info on where $Object1 is declared? When you declare an object in drools it automatically creates getter and setter methods for each attribute of the object. I'm not sure how a library will help as you just need a clear way to set a number of different attributes (which you can do via the auto-generated setters).

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your support @Neil .As I see, String.valueOf... is also some default/auto created method.

code'declare Object  
       att1 : String  
       att2 : String 
       variable: String
end

rule "R1"
 salience(2)
    when
    then
     insert(new Object("xxx","a","att1"));
     insert(new Object("yyy","c","att2"));
end

rule "R2"
 salience(1)
    when
    $Object1 : Object()
    then
        System.out.println(String.valueOf($Object1.getAtt1()));
end'code

I need below output, xxx 1st value for att1 and c 2nd value for att2:
xxx
c

Comment: Can you put that code in your main question (and surround with code tags to format it) so it's clearer?